# Why does system call fails?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I try to compile simple utility (kernel 3.4.67), which 
all it does is trying to use system call very simply as following:

```
int main(void)
{
   int rc;

   printf("hello 1\n");

   rc = system("echo hello again");
   printf("system returned %d\n",rc);
   rc = system("ls -l");
   printf("system returned %d\n",rc);

  return 0;

}
```

**Yet, system call fails as you can see in the following log:**

```
root@w812a_kk:/ # /sdcard/test
hello 1
system returned 32512
system returned 32512
```

**I compile it as following**:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc   -s -static  -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes test.c -o test
```

That's really wierd becuase I used system in past in different linux and never had any issue with it.
I even tried another cross cpompiler but I get the same failure.

**Version of kernel & cross compiler**:

```
# busybox  uname -a
   Linux localhost 3.4.67 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 28 18:18:33 CST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.7-2013.03-20130313 - Linaro GCC 2013.03) 4.7.3 20130226 (prerelease)
```

**EDIT**:

```
root@w812a_kk:/ # echo hello again && echo $? && echo $0
hello again
0
tmp-mksh
root@w812a_kk:/ #
```

But I did find something interesting:
On calling test_expander() withing the main, it works OK. so I suspect that maybe system call try to find a binary which is not founded ?

```
int test_expander(void)
{
  pid_t pid;
     char *const parmList[] = {"/system/bin/busybox", "echo", "hello", NULL};

     if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        perror("fork error");
     else if (pid == 0) {
        execv("/system/bin/busybox", parmList);
        printf("Return not expected. Must be an execv error.n");
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any idea.

Ran

Comment: What does `$ echo hello again` return in shell? Try copying the "hello again" in a buffer and pass it to the `system()`.

Comment: It returns nothing (that's the problem). Seems like system call does nothing at all :(, I don't know why

Comment: I meant what is `$?` after doing `echo` as stated in previous command?

Comment: Can I check it from code, Do you mean doing in code : system("echo $?")

Comment: No. On shell of your arm board execute the following and provide the output. `echo hello again && echo $?` Also provide output of `echo $0`.

Comment: I think I got the answer, added it as a solution. many thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of system(), 32512 decimal, is 7F00 in hex.
This value is strangely similar to 0x7F, which is the result of system() if `/bin/sh` can not be executed. It seems there is some problem with byte ordering (big/little endian). Very strange.

Update: while writing the answer, you edited the question and pulled in something about `/system/bin/busybox`.

Probably you simply don't have `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what happens

From system man page:

```
 The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process
       that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)
       as follows:

           execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
```

But in my filesystem `sh` is founded only /system/bin , not in /bin

So I better just use execv instead. (I can't do static link becuase it's read-only filesystem)

Thanks,
Ran